# Can't copy/paste in GUI

Tags: monero-wallet-gui

I get nothing on right click in any field in the GUI wallet. Is this a bug? I sent a transaction by typing the address manually and it worked but it's not really usable like this.

Comment: I can copy paste just fine (Linux, select, middle click).You may want to state the OS you are using.

Answer (score 2):

You can copy nearly every field in the GUI with an double-click or the copy symbol and you can paste in any field with strg+v.